# How to operate the databases in MongoDB in nodejs via mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The MongoDB has set the property 'auth' with true, in commond line, you must log in Admin first, and then you can operate other databases.

In nodejs, I wrote the connection like this:

mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:pwd@127.0.0.1 :27017/test');

But it' s failed, do I need to connect Admin first, if so, how?

Comment: You need to log as Admin in MongoDb Shell and create user in test database via db.createUser and then access this database with this user credentials from your code.

Comment: But I don't want to log as Admin in MongoDB Shell, is there a way I can do this in my code?